# Bug in select() statement with inlining?

Tags: model-checking, spin, promela

I would have posted this in the [spinroot Bug Reports](http://spinroot.com/fluxbb/viewforum.php?id=3), but the spinroot forum is not currently accepting new users... If someone out there in charge of that is reading this, please let me in :)

Something very odd is happening when I try to use the select statement. Promela does not allow `select()` to be called on the field of a struct, so I have to make a temporary variable like this:

```
typedef someStruct {
    int someField;
}

someStruct struct;

inline SetSelect() {
    int temp;
    select(temp: -1 .. 1);
    struct.someField = temp;
}

init{
    SetSelect();
}
```

This runs fine. I tested it and `struct.someField` is correctly set to either -1, 0, or 1. *However,* when I try to just put the inlined code straight into the `init()` process, I get a syntax error. The code looks like this:

```
typedef someStruct {
    int someField;
}

someStruct struct;

init{
    int temp;
    select(temp: -1 .. 1);
    struct.someField = temp;
}
```

And the error message is:

`spin: select_test.pml:9, Error: syntax error   saw ''-' = 45'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BUG**:

Indeed, it looks like a bug for version `6.4.6` of *Spin*.
*(The bug is fixed in version `6.4.7`)*

Interestingly, You can make it go away by simply writing `temp :` instead of `temp:`.

I suggest you to contact [Gerard Holzmann](http://spinroot.com/gerard/) for filing a bug report. I would also mention the fact that *select* does not seem to work with a *struct field*, perhaps that can be fixed too *(even if it might be by design)*.

---

**SUGGESTION:**

I am not entirely happy of creating an alias variable to get around the issue of the built-in select function with struct fields. Since the implementation of **select** is rather trivial, as can be found in the [**docs**](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/select.html), I would introduce a novel inline function *to replace the built-in select* function:

```cpp
typedef Struct
{
    int field;
}

inline my_select (var, lower, upper)
{
    var = lower;
    do
        :: var < upper -> var++;
        :: break;
    od;
}

init
{
    Struct st;
    my_select(st.field, -1, 1);
    printf("%d\n", st.field);
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I want to note that using a struct field in a for loop also throws a syntax error. I will ask him about that as well.